# Hypergraphs where the edges are subsets of the union of the edges and nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a formulation of hypergraphs such that the hypergraph $H = (V, E)$ consists of a set of nodes $V = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ and a set of edges $E = \{E_1, E_2, ...,E_m\}$, where $E_i \subseteq V \cup E$ instead of $E_i \subseteq V$?

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to represent a relationship between an edge and a node. Thank you!

Edit for clarification:

I've seen a hypergraph defined as a graph where an edge is a subset of the set of nodes in the graph. Therefore, we have edges that can connect more than two nodes. For example if $A, B, C \in V$, I can define an edge $E_1 = \{A, B, C\}$ that connects the two nodes and represents some relationship between the three nodes.

What I'm asking is whether there is a variant of hypergraphs where I could define an edge such as $E_2 = \{E_1, D\}$ for some $D \in V$, representing a relationship between the node $D$ and the edge $E_1$ (more specifically between $D$ and the relationship between $A$, $B$, and $C$).

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow. Please be a bit more specific with your question, if you can. I would expect an edge to be represented by a pair of vertices, not just a subset of the set of vertices. What type of construction do you have in mind? In many areas people have adjusted the notion of graphs according to their particular needs, inventing timed graphs and metagraphs and others. Maybe you could start by explaining what your notion of a hypergraph is and then what you would like to change.

Comment: Just added some clarification!

Comment: Something is very weird about your formulation of the problem in the first paragraph. The elements of $E$ should not be subsets of $E$. This leads to set-theoretical paradoxes.

Comment: @SamHopkins That's precisely my question is whether one can define the elements of $E$ as subsets of $E$. Could you expand on what kind of set-theoretical paradoxes it leads to?

Comment: At a minimum, something like $E_1 = \{E_1\}$ violates the axiom of regularity (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: Don't you mean you want a node set $V$, an hyperedge set $E$ of subsets of $V$, and an additional set $E'$ of subsets of $V \cup E$? Then, $E'$ would represent relations between nodes and edges and the definition would be consistent.